# Rolling Precision

Tags: python, dataframe, prediction

I have a dataframe with binary predictions (data['ypred'] which is either 1 or 0) and actual realizations (data['y']) and I would like to write a function that computes a rolling Precision (that is percentage of correct predictions out of all predictions) for the last n values (the data is sorted by date already). Below is an example for the last 2 observations (notice how the first row is NA, and the last row is 50% since only 1 out of 2 is correct):

```
 dict = [{'ypred': '1','y': '1','rolWinProb': 'NA'},
 {'ypred': '1','y': '1','rolWinProb': '100'},
 {'ypred': '0','y': '1','rolWinProb': '100'},
 {'ypred': '0','y': '1','rolWinProb': '100'},
 {'ypred': '1','y': '0','rolWinProb': '50'}]

 data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Maybe something like this:

```
data[(data['y'] ==1 ) & (data['ypred']==1)].rolling(10)
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected output

Comment: Good idea, I added an example and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, where you've got your values from, but what you can do:

```py
N=2
data["rollwinprob"]=data["ypred"].eq(data["y"]).rolling(N).mean().mul(100)
```

Ref. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html